# JNI to bind C++ and JAVA : undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to link a Java swing frontend to the c++ backend using JNI. I am able to generate a class file and header file for that class. I could also write the .cpp file and also generate a library file. But when I try to run my application I get an error undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0.
I went through many examples on stackoverflow but none of it worked in my case. I made sure I have libgcc, libgcj and libstd++. Also added pragma GCC java_exceptions on the top of the JNI header file. 
But none of these worked.

Java file - InitJNI.java

```
public class InitJNI {
public native String callMethod(String str);

public static void init(String s){
    System.out.println("-------inside InitJNI.java--------");
    System.loadLibrary("eg1");
    System.out.println("Library loaded in InitJNI--------");
    InitJNI init1 = new InitJNI();
    init1.callMethod(s);
}
```

}

JNI header file - InitJNI.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class org_openscience_jchempaint_application_InitJNI */

#ifndef _Included_InitJNI
#define _Included_InitJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     InitJNI
 * Method:    callMethod
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_InitJNI_callMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Cpp file - InitJNI.cpp

```
#include "InitJNI.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#pragma GCC java_exceptions


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_InitJNI_callMethod
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject, jstring string){
    char buf[128];
    const char *str = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, NULL);
    printf("%s", str);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, str);
}
```

I am trying to create a shared lib using command:

```
g++ -shared -fpic -o libeg1.so -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/linux InitJNI.cpp
```

Which generates libeg1.so file. But my application does not run. It gives me 
undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0
Any help with this is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `-lstdc++` to the end of the command:  `g++ -shared -fpic -o libeg1.so -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/linux InitJNI.cpp -lstdc++`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, but I already tried it. But its not working.

Comment: Did you link to "JNI.so"? Try also doing something like -m64 or -m32 and `-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` Add each one of them, one at a time.

Comment: @Brandon Thank you for the help. So -static-libgcc, static-libstdc++ and -m64 created the library file but then I hit the same error again, when I tried to run the application. However, when I tried using -static, it gave me the following error: /lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/crtbeginT.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.             Is this the one creating problem? Any idea how I fix this? Also you mentioned about linking JNI.so. How can I ensure that I am linking to JNI.so? Sorry for the silly questions, but I am a newbie in JNI.

Comment: Do you also get any such errors when using [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) to link the JNI library?

Comment: @SamuelAudet I haven't used JavaCpp before.